# Kendo UI grid rendering

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-observable

I have a scenario here, Consider there are two kendo ui grids(jquery), Grid1 and Grid2 both are of same schema. On adding data in the first grid ie Grid-1, should automatically reflect the grid-2. However the same data I am changing in the Grid-2 should not affect the Grid-1 unless I have made an explicit event to change the same. In my case it is working bi directionally not the way I want to be. I am using Kendo observable.